# Find text string in column, copy to defined range Loop

Tags: vba, loops, dynamic, range

I've had a look through the forums and couldn't quite find what I'm looking for.

Basically I have some data filed stored in a directory where I have a master file.  The code looks through file names that are stacked in a list.  As the files open, the code should look for a file name.  When the file has been identified (there is no clue on the import file name.xls), the data needs to be copied from the first row down and third column across until the data breaks/finishes.   the code then needs to reference a range on the master sheet where the data is to be pasted to after the contents have been cleared.  Once complete, the code loops to the next file and repeats.

Their are five names/strings.

I'm obviously a complete novice, any help, guidance fully appreciated.

James

```
Sub import()

    Dim mydir As String, r As Range, fn As String, msg As String
    Dim LR As Long
    Dim x As Long
    Dim bottomC As Integer
    Dim c As Range



    'loop through files in Prism dir and import  reports named in list .
    mydir = "C:\desktop\”

    For Each r In Range("F8", Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

        fn = Dir(mydir & r.Value)

        If fn = "" Then
            msg = msg & vbLf & r.Value
        Else
            For Each c In Sheets("DataToImport").Range("A8")

                If c.Value = "DataSet1" Then

                    Sheets("DataToImport ").Range("A8:C" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1).Copy

                                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Mapping").Range("AC4:AE5000").ClearContents

                                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Mapping").Range("AC4:AE5000").Paste



       ' For Each c In Sheets("DataToImport").Range("A8:20")

                  'Sheets("DataToImport").Range ("A8")

                     ' If c.Value = " DataSet2" Then

                         '.Sheets("AIMSPROD").Range("A8:C" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1).Copy

                           'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Mapping").Range("AO4:AQ5000").ClearContents

                                 'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Mapping").Range("AO4:AQ5000").Paste



                    'For Each c In Sheets("DataToImport ").Range("A8:20")

                             '.Sheets("DataToImport ").Range ("A8")

                                     'If c.Value = " DataSet3" Then

                                         '.Sheets("DataToImport ").Range("A8:C" & .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1).Copy

                                              'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Mapping").Range("AF4:AH5000").ClearContents

                                                'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Mapping").Range("AF4:AH5000").Paste



                         ' For Each c In Sheets("DataToImport ").Range("A8:20")

                                     '.Sheets("DataToImport ").Range ("A8")

                                           'If c.Value = " DataSet4" Then

                                            '.Sheets("DataToImport ").Range("A8:C" & .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1).Copy

                                                'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Mapping").Range("AL4:AN5000").ClearContents

                                                  'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Mapping").Range("AL4:AN5000").Paste







                                        ' For Each c In Sheets("DataToImport ").Range("A8:20")

                                                 '.Sheets("DataToImport ").Range ("A8")

                                                            'If c.Value = "DataSet5" Then

                                                              '.Sheets("DataToImport ").Range("A8:C" & .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1).Copy

                                                                     'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Mapping").Range("AI4:AK5000").ClearContents

                                                                       ' ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Mapping").Range("AI4:AK5000").Paste



                  .Close False

            End With

        End If

    Next

    If Len(msg) Then

        MsgBox "Not found" & msg

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Wanna format your code?

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code, formatted and without the commented out code:

```
Sub import()
    Dim mydir As String, r As Range, fn As String, msg As String
    Dim LR As Long
    Dim x As Long
    Dim bottomC As Integer
    Dim c As Range
    'loop through files in Prism dir and import  reports named in list .
    mydir = "C:\desktop\”"
    For Each r In Range("F8", Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        fn = Dir(mydir & r.Value)
        If fn = "" Then
            msg = msg & vbLf & r.Value
        Else
            For Each c In Sheets("DataToImport").Range("A8")
                If c.Value = "DataSet1" Then
                    Sheets("DataToImport ").Range("A8:C" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1).Copy
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Mapping").Range("AC4:AE5000").ClearContents
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Mapping").Range("AC4:AE5000").Paste
                   .Close False
            End With
        End If
    Next
    If Len(msg) Then
        MsgBox "Not found" & msg
    End If
End Sub
```

...This wont even start, because you have an `End With` without a `With` in there, and because there is not with block, `.Close False` is not valid.

There is also no point in `For Each c In`...`.Range("A8")`, as you are looping over one cell, `Range("A8")`. Use `Set c` to set `c` to the range explicitly.

Also, if you copy something in excel, then change the value of any other cell, it will cancel the copy, so these three statements are in the wrong order:

```
.Copy
.ClearContents
.Paste
```

Finally, You can't do Range(x).Paste, you can only do `Range.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll`, (Or you can do `Sheet.Paste` with the range selected)

With all these corrections, your code looks like this:

//Edited code to correspond to comments below//

```
Sub import()
    Dim mydir As String, r As Range, fn As String, msg As String
    Dim LR As Long
    Dim x As Long
    Dim bottomC As Integer
    Dim c As Range
    'loop through files in Prism dir and import  reports named in list .
    mydir = "C:\desktop\"
    For Each r In Range("F8", Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        fn = Dir(mydir & r.Value)
        If fn = "" Then
            msg = msg & vbLf & r.Value
        Else
            Set c = Sheets("DataToImport").Range("A8")
            If c.Value = "DataSet1" Then
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Mapping").Range("AC4:AE5000").ClearContents
                Sheets("DataToImport ").Range("A8:C" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1).Copy
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Mapping").Range("AC4").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
            ElseIf c.Value = "DataSet2" Then
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Mapping").Range("AC4:AE5000").ClearContents
                Sheets("DataToImport ").Range("A8:C" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1).Copy
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Mapping").Range("AC4").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
               '.Close False '-Put this somewhere else
            End If
        End If
    Next
    If Len(msg) Then
        MsgBox "Not found" & msg
    End If
End Sub
```

One other thing - its bat practice to provide a range with more than one cell as a paste destination, because for example, if you copy `A1:A2`, then paste in `B1:B4`, it will paste `A1:A2` twice, which is probably not what you want.

Apologies for if this got condescending, that wasn't my intention. Also, I didn't want to provide a full solution without you trying to fix this.

Hope this gets you on the right track!

Comment: Not at all, many thanks indeed - appreciate the advice..  This all makes sense.  Just one last thing. Is there a loop in the loop required?  after "DataSet1" has been found and the data copied to "DataSet1"'s past range in the target sheet, the Code will need to identify the other four strings "DataSet2", "DataSet3" etc etc.  All with their own respective ranges.  How should this be handled?

Comment: The if...end if block can be repeated. You can do `if c.value = "Dataset1" elseif c.value = "Dataset2" end if` etc. I have edited my answer above to illustrate this